# AWK not printing properly

Tags: awk

This is what I need to do..

I have a textfile and parse it using awk. The output should be in json format. It should look like this:

```
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"}
}
```

Now, this is how the content of textfile looks like:

```
Record X
   Key1 is Value1, Key2 is Value2
Record Y
   Key1 is Value1, Key2 is Value2
Record Z
   Key1 is Value1, Key2 is Value2
Record A
   Key1 is Value1, Key2 is Value2
```

I tried creating a script to produce the output that I want, I'm in the first part however Im already stuck with printing the line. This is my script:

```
 awk 
'BEGIN { print "{" }
      { if($0 ~ /^Record /){print "\"" $0 "\":" }}
 END  { print "}" }' myRecord.txt
```

And the output is this..

```
{
":ecord X
":ecord Y
":ecord Z
":ecord A
}
```

I do not understand why that kind of script will produce something like that. 
Kindly tell me what's wrong. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that your input file was created on Windows and so has control-Ms at the end of each line causing corruption when printing the lines. Remove them with dos2unix or similar before running your script. Do NOT use any getline solution suggested below as that would be the wrong approach and introduce a lot of caveats and complexity (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline).

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ print "{" }
NR%2 { id = $0; next }
{
    sub(/^ +/,"")
    gsub(/ is /,"\":\"")
    gsub(/, /,"\", \"")
    printf "%s\"%s\" : { \"%s\"}", (c++?",\n":""), id, $0
}
END{ print "\n}" }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `printf "%s\"%s\" : { \"%s\"}", (c++?",\n":""), id, $0` you could have used `printf (c++?",\n":"")"\"%s\" : { \"%s\"}", id, $0`.  Is there any pros or cons about this?

Comment: Yes you're right! The problem was the control M's or whatever because the textfile was made in Windows. Most of think that the problem was in the code, thanks to you! :)

Comment: @Jotne Mostly I just feel that using string concatenation to create the format string obfuscates the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` without using `getline`

```
awk -F"[ ,]*" 'BEGIN {print "{"} /^Record/ {a=$0;next} {print "\""a"\" : { \""$2"\":\""$4"\", \""$5"\":\""$7"\"},"} END {print "}"}'
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
}
```

If you get problems with last `,` you can do like this:

```
awk -F"[ ,]*" -v f=$(cat file | wc -l) 'BEGIN {print "{"} /^Record/ {a=$0;next} {print "\""a"\" : { \""$2"\":\""$4"\", \""$5"\":\""$7"\"}"(NR==f?"":",")} END {print "}"}' file
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"}
}
```

Or all in only `awk`

```
awk -F"[ ,]*" 'BEGIN {print "{"} FNR==NR {f=NR;next} /^Record/ {a=$0;next} {print "\""a"\" : { \""$2"\":\""$4"\", \""$5"\":\""$7"\"}"(FNR==f?"":",")} END {print "}"}' file{,}
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through awk's getline function,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "{\n"}/^Record/{var=$0; getline; w=$1; x=$3; y=$4; z=$6;}{printf "\""var"\"" " : { ""\""w"\""":\""x"\", \""y"\":\""z"\"},\n"} END{printf "}\n"}' file
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1,", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1,", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1,", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1,", "Key2":"Value2"},
}
```

Through GNU awk's `gsub` function,

```
$ awk -v RS="Record" 'BEGIN{print "{"} gsub(/\n/,"",$0){gsub(/.$/,"",$4); print "\""RS" "$1"\" : { \""$2"\":\""$4"\", \""$5"\":\""$7"\"},"} END{print "}"}' file
{
"Record X" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Y" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record Z" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
"Record A" : { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"},
}
```

Comment: Last one is better since it does not use `getline`, but you still have  an `,` extra on last line.  You need to mention that you need `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in `RS` (Normal `awk` supports max one character)

Comment: I did just change my post to `/^Record/ {a=$0;next}` to avoid problems if there are other line, and this can also be used instead of `getline`, and are more portable than `RS="Record"`.  And I would suggest you change from `gsub(/.$/,"",$4)` to `gsub(/,$/,"",$4)`. The `.` removes any last characters, but you only like to remove the `,`

Comment: @Jotne the last character in `$4` must be a `,`, so i put `.` in the pattern.

Comment: Since it must be `,` why then `.`?  Its more easy for other to understand what you are trying to remove by showing it.  Yes it works, but I see no reason to use `.`

Answer (score 0):

Using your flow logic:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { print "{" }
        /^Record /{
            if (c){printf ",\n"}
            printf("\"%s\":",$0);next}
            {
            gsub("is",":")
            gsub("  *","\"")
            printf(" {%s\"}",$0)
            c++
            }
        END  { print "\n}" }'  infile
```

Comment: Smart way to handle not showing `,` on last line :)